# How to restore .git folder with local commits and stash changes which i saved

Tags: git, github

Unfortunately, by mistake, I deleted the .git folder from my project.

I was trying to delete swp file but by mistake, I deleted the .git folder.

I had many local commits and branches which I have not pushed on the server and also some changes were present on my stash

How can I restore the git folder and with my local commits and stash changes?

It would be great is someone help me with this

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Everything was in the `.git` folder. You've deleted all of it—there's nothing to restore *unless* your computer made a backup of the `.git` folder. Git itself doesn't do that.

Comment: using any software?

Comment: If you're on a mac, and you have Time Machine running, perhaps Time Machine made a backup. If you're on something else, or don't have Time Machine and a backup drive, I have no other suggestions.

Comment: What is your OS ?

Comment: I'm using mac OS